# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp, nullpointerexception, tomcat7

Something truly bizarre is happening with my Tomcat7 deployment.  Either that, or I'm way too tired.  Here's the skinny...

I have a very simple Tomcat7 webapp that I'm developing through Eclipse(Juno).  One of my JSP files includes a form.  When the form is submitted, a servlet queries the database and returns two parameters back to the same jsp via session.setAttribute.

Everything works fine, but if I start mucking around with the servlet, I suddenly get an HTTP 500 errors on the JSP page.  The only way I've been able to resolve it is to go through a bizarre ritual of removing all Java-related content from the JSP, then slowly adding it in and refreshing.  I can't tell if this is a Tomcat issue, Servlet issue, Firefox issue, or some combination of the above.

For clarity, here are some code snippets:

Jsp Code:

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var searchResults = '<%= ((String[][])session.getAttribute("searchResults")).length %>';
      var additionalResults = '<%= session.getAttribute("additionalResults") %>';
      ...
    </script>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Tomcat Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /test.jsp at line 32


30:   <body>
31:     <script type='text/javascript'>
32:         var searchResults = '<%= ((String[][])session.getAttribute("searchResults")).length %>';
33:         var additionalResults = '<%= session.getAttribute("additionalResults") %>';
34: 


Stacktrace:        
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:93)
```

I know for a FACT that the database is returning proper values, so line 32 should not be throwing an exception or a NullPointer.  Line 93 is simply:

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

I even get the Tomcat error when line 32 is commented out?!?!

To try to debug, I simplified the contents of the script tag to be:

```
alert('<%= session.getAttribute("searchResults") %>');
```

And edited my servlet to read:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String redirectedPage = "/test.jsp";
    request.getSession().setAttribute("searchResults", "Bob");
    RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(redirectedPage);
    reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);
  }
}
```

But the resultant popup shows 'null'.  I've also tried restarting MySQL and Tomcat many times, in various order.

So I'm at a complete loss as to what's going on.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried '<%= ((String)session.getAttribute("searchResults")).length %>'

Comment: Are you sure `session.getAttribute("additionalResults")` is not null? Also, the reference to line 93 refers to the _generated .java class_, not your .jsp file.

Comment: alert('<%= session.getAttribute("searchResults")%>'); prints 'null' but it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post the answer to this.  It turned out I was closing the JDBC connection, so the ResultSet object was inaccessible by the time it came back to the jsp.  I've since updated that code and moved the results out of the ResultSet object and into parameters that I pass back via the HTTPRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

use this for your jsp code

```
    if('<%= session.getAttribute("searchResults") %>' !="null")
          {
           var str = '<%= (String)session.getAttribute("searchResults") %>' 
           searchResults = str.length;
           alert(searchResults)

          }
```

Comment: No, that won't work.  session.getAttribute("searchResults") is returning null, so making any additional calls just throws a NullPointerException.  What I need to understand is why null is being returned if I am not modifying the servlet code...

Comment: run your servlet first , it redirect you at your jsp page.